# Swagger json Editor : undefiend Error

Tags: css, facebook, spring

when I use Swagger Editor, I have an one undefined Error In Rendering

my code is here:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: AccountBalance
host: localhost:2625
basePath: /accountbalance
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
  - text/xml
produces:
  - application/json
  - text/html
paths:
  /:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: acc
          in: query
          description: acc
          type: integer
          format: long

      responses:
        200:
          description:  List all AccBal
          schema:
            title: acc
            type: array
            items:
             $ref: '#/definitions/accountbalance'

  definitions:
  accountbalance:
    properties:
      Balance:
        type: integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The `definitions:` object should be at the root level

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: AccountBalance
host: localhost:2625
basePath: /accountbalance
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
  - text/xml
produces:
  - application/json
  - text/html
paths:
  /:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: acc
          in: query
          description: acc
          type: integer
          format: long

      responses:
        200:
          description:  List all AccBal
          schema:
            title: acc
            type: array
            items:
             $ref: '#/definitions/accountbalance'
definitions:
    accountbalance:
      properties:
        Balance:
          type: integer
```